# Values is not picking up in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am new in Powershell and I have write a small utility in PS in which I provide values in $firstDate and $lastDate but when I run this program my these two value is not printed in $value.. Can anyone please look and help me on this.

```
$firstDate=Get-Date -Year.2018 -Month.12 -Day.1
$lastDate=Get-Date -Year.2020 -Month.1 -Day.12
$value = $firstDate -eq $lastDate
```

Comment: Could you please suggest what i did wrong in $firstDate $lastDate when i pass values in that is that the correct syntax

Comment: `$firstDate=Get-Date -Year.2018 -Month.12 -Day.1` **-->** `$firstDate=Get-Date -Year 2018 -Month 12 -Day 1`.
You need to remove the `dot(.)` and pass only the values. BTW, `$values` will give you a boolean as you are comparing both the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use `-year` or `-month` or `-day` to provide the values, you have to define the value for it after a `space`. You are using dot notation which is used mostly to access property or method of the variable. (Note from `@mklement0`: PowerShell also supports : as the separator between parameter name and argument)

```
$firstDate=Get-Date -Year 2018 -Month 12 -Day 1
$lastDate=Get-Date -Year 2020 -Month 1 -Day 12
$value = $firstDate -eq $lastDate
# value = False.
```

This will give you the value of `false` because the dates dont match up.

**UPDATE**

The above code will never equal true even if you set the year, month and day to be the same. This is because time factor of the DateTime will be off. You can do the following to make sure you compare only `Dates`

```
$value = $firstDate.Date -eq $lastDate.Date
```

This will only compare the Date and ignore the Time.

Comment: Indeed; perhaps worth mentioning that PowerShell also supports `:` as the separator between parameter name and argument: `Get-Date -Year:2018 -Month:12 -Day:1`